# can I use experimental filesystem in ndk with libc++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, c++-experimental

I'm trying to use experimental filesystem in an android project with ndk r17 and I'm using STL c++_static but I got this :

```
undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__current_path(std::__ndk1::error_code*)'
```

I show some topics that suggest adding -lstdc++fs to the linker arguments but the linker can't find this library

does current ndk support this experimental feature or not ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not yet: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/609

Support for it is coming, but the libc++ tests are going to require some effort to get working for Android (the `std::filesystem` tests are not particularly cross-compile friendly) and I haven't had the time to do that yet.

Comment: is it available now? I am getting error: error: undefined reference to 'std::__ndk1::__fs::filesystem::__file_size(std::__ndk1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__ndk1::error_code*)' even now

Comment: See the linked bug.